# How Exception will be thrown from orElseThrow method in JAVA 8?

Tags: java, option-type

I have one field called **isExist** and it is either false or true in line #1.
based on this, in line#2 either Optional.empty() is executed or Optional.of(1) is getting executed but never Exception is thrown from **orElseThrow** method in line#2.

can anyone please explain when Exception will be thrown ? on which condition Exception will be thrown ?

```
line#1 final boolean isExist  = (user != null && CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(user.getIds())
                && user.getIds().contains(id));

line#2 (isExist ? Optional.empty() : Optional.of(1)).orElseThrow(
                () -> new Exception());
```

Comment: Why don't you run the code and find out?

Comment: I tried running but not able to reproduce this

Comment: You need to show a complete example which reproduces your problem -- when `isExist` is  `true`, an exception will be thrown.

Comment: I hope this is an exercise, and you aren’t really using Optional instead of the much cleaner and simpler `if (!isExist) throw new Exception();` in application code.

Comment: @VGR agree but that should be `if (isExist) ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From line1, it will assign true/false to isExist variable.

So we have 2 possibility here.

```
isExist = true or isExist = false;
```

At line 2, the tertiary condition can be understand as:

```
Optional optional = null;
if(isExist){
   optional = Optional.empty();
}else{
   optional = Optional.of(1)
}
optional.orElseThrow(() -> new Exception());
```

orElseThrow only throw exception when optional variable is empty, it mean when isExist = true. If isExist = false, nothing happen.
You can see below signature to understand the basic concept of orElseThrow ...

```
public void orElseThrow(Exception ex){
  if(!isPresent()){
     throw ex;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `Optional` for this. It's just not necessary. Use plain imperative code:

```
if (!isExist) {
  throw new Exception();
}
// You don't show what you do with the result, but presumably you do something
// like return or assign to a variable:
return 1;
```